# SQL Server Reporting Service Connection Error

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to connect to ssrs using C#, I wrote the following code:

```
string UserId = Session["UserId"].ToString();
                        MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("username", "mypassword", "mydomainname");
                        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;

                        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("my Report Server URL"); // Report Server URL
                        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Attendance_Reports/Employee02"; // Report Name
                        ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("ReportUser", UserId);
                        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Timeout = 200000000;
                        this.MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
                        MyReportViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;
                        MyReportViewer.ShowBackButton = true;
                        MyReportViewer.ShowRefreshButton = true;
                        MyReportViewer.ShowReportBody = true;
                        MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
```

but I get this error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 197.50.102.166:443

How can I prevent calling port 443 and call only port 80?

Comment: Why do you think calling over the port 443  is the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: the remote server refuse it

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80d7419b-6523-443e-9510-0ddded7d4081/reportviewer-control-appears-to-be-forcing-ssl-and-failing?forum=sqlreportingservices) to a similar problem helpful.

The "ReportServerUrl" property should be set to the SSRS Web Service URL rather than the Report Manager URL. This means that instead of using the URL that you would browse to when viewing the report, which is typically configured as `http://<reportserver>/reports`, you should use something like `http://<reportserver>/reportserver`.